# try-catch & async await change order in js?

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I have a question.
I make function test() and assert();

I test my code.
but result is different my things.

when i use async await in function test().
the result is

```
should support flattening of nested arrays : fail
should support filtering of arrays : fail
support notEqual : ok
adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 : ok
```

but i remove async await in function test().
the result is

```
support notEqual : ok
adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 : ok
should support flattening of nested arrays : fail
should support filtering of arrays : fail
```

why?

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const sum = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};

const isEven = n => {
  return n % 2 == 0;
};

const appendLazy = (arr, data, time) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      arr.push(data);
      resolve(arr);
    }, time);
  });
};

async function test(msg, callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
    console.log(`${msg} : ok`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`${msg} : fail`);
  }
}

const assert = {
  equal: (targetA, targetB) => {
    if (targetA !== targetB) throw Error;
  },
  notEqual: (targetA, targetB) => {
    if (targetA === targetB) throw Error;
  }
};

test("support notEqual", () => {
  assert.notEqual(undefined, null); //pass
});

test("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3", () => {
  assert.equal(1 + 2, 3); //pass
});

test("should support flattening of nested arrays", function() {
  assert.detailEqual([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5]); //fail
});

test("should support filtering of arrays", function() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  assert.detailEqual(_.filter(arr, isEven), [2, 4, 5, 6]); //fail
});
```

I must use async await in my test function.
why the reason different???

Comment: What is `assert.detailEqual`?

Comment: that's because console.log does not wait for callback to finish

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `async` function that you have is of no use.
For it to work, the `await` should receive `Promise` as a return value.

Based on the functions you posted, none of it is returning any promise (except `appendLazy` but it was never used).

It is as good as not using any `async`-`await` and whichever function finishes will print the results first.

Comment: Yeah.
But I have `Promise` other code.
so, I need `async await`. TT